# Ionic 2 - After moving between multiple tabs when i click on the physical back button it closes the app, but does not navigate to the previous tab

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using ionic 2 with which i am facing the below mentioned issue:

Pressing Back button after I move between tabs does not bring me back to the previous tab.. but instead closes the app.

i am using angular 4 with ionic

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: There's nothing to fix, it's suposed to behave this way. When you click another tab it sets the root to that tab page.